# Shouldn't getElementById return an object containing sub objects?

Tags: javascript

Using the following code I was expecting to get an object which contains the sub elements

```
var MemberDiv=document.getElementById("idProfileMainContainer");
console.log(MemberDiv.length);
```

Using the above code I get "undefined". I'm confused. I thought it should have an object array that contains all sub elements.

Ultimately I am trying to find the sub `<div />` with the `<span />` that has "Board Position" in it.

```
<div id="idContainer8592665" class="fieldContainer simpleTextContainer">
    <div class="fieldSubContainer labeledTextContainer">

        <div class="fieldLabel">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_titleLabel" title="Cannot be edited, Administrator access only">Board Position</span>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldBody">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_DropDownLabel8592665">Webmaster</span><input name="FunctionalBlock1$ctl00$ctl00$MemberForm$memberFormRepeater$ctl22$ctl03" type="hidden">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't trying to get the length of an array, you'll need to check the `childNodes` of `MemberDiv`

Comment: @FredWilson, You are mistaken. Where did you get that info from?

Comment: not very difficult to look up what it actually does return .. it's well documented and easily found

Comment: @charlietfl I understand that it "should" be easy to look up but for at least the last few hours I have been googling my tail off and cannot seem to figure out the correct search criteria to get me a useful answer.

Comment: Just put "getElementById" in google...most likely first result will be the MDN docs. Those docs are also easily searched internally

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `getElementById` is not an array, but *one* node (or none) as you can find [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID

To get the element you are targetting, you could use this ES6 script:

```js
// Select all div.fieldLabel descendants of #idContainer8592665 and find one that has 
// the text content we look for.
var div = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#idContainer8592665 div.fieldLabel'))
               .find( div => div.textContent.includes('Board Position'));

// Show the text of the div element we found
console.log(div.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div id="idContainer8592665" class="fieldContainer simpleTextContainer">
    <div class="fieldSubContainer labeledTextContainer">

        <div class="fieldLabel">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_titleLabel" title="Cannot be edited, Administrator access only">Board Position</span>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldBody">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_DropDownLabel8592665">Webmaster</span><input name="FunctionalBlock1$ctl00$ctl00$MemberForm$memberFormRepeater$ctl22$ctl03" type="hidden">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In ES5 compatible script it would look like this:

```js
// Select all div.fieldLabel descendants of #idContainer8592665 and find one that has 
// the text content we look for.
var parent = document.getElementById('idContainer8592665');
var div = [].filter.call(parent.getElementsByClassName('fieldLabel'),
             function (div) {
                 return div.textContent.indexOf('Board Position') != -1;
             }).pop();

// Show the text of the div element we found
console.log(div.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div id="idContainer8592665" class="fieldContainer simpleTextContainer">
    <div class="fieldSubContainer labeledTextContainer">

        <div class="fieldLabel">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_titleLabel" title="Cannot be edited, Administrator access only">Board Position</span>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldBody">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_DropDownLabel8592665">Webmaster</span><input name="FunctionalBlock1$ctl00$ctl00$MemberForm$memberFormRepeater$ctl22$ctl03" type="hidden">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is get the collection of span elements. I then step through this collection, checking if the `textContent` is 'Board Position'. If so, I walk back up the DOM tree until I reach a div node. I then print it's class (the only attribute it has in your html) and also, the outerHTML.

If there may be more that one matching element, `result` should be initialized to `[]`, you should check for `.length > 0` instead of `== undefined`, you should push the element into result `result.push(elem)` instead of setting it to the elem with `result = elem` and finally, you should iterate through the results, rather than showing the only single one.

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByTag(tag,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tag)}
// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types - (array-like objects)
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need


window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
  var spans = allByTag('span');
  var result=undefined;
  
  forEach(spans, findParentIfMatching);
  if (result != undefined)
    {
       console.log(result.className);
       console.log('*******************************');
       console.log(result.outerHTML);
    }
  function findParentIfMatching(elem,index,collection)
  {
    if (elem.textContent == 'Board Position')
      {
        while (elem.nodeName != 'DIV')
          elem = elem.parentNode;
        result = elem;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="idContainer8592665" class="fieldContainer simpleTextContainer">
    <div class="fieldSubContainer labeledTextContainer">

        <div class="fieldLabel">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_titleLabel" title="Cannot be edited, Administrator access only">Board Position</span>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldBody">
            <span id="FunctionalBlock1_ctl00_ctl00_MemberForm_memberFormRepeater_ctl22_DropDownLabel8592665">Webmaster</span><input name="FunctionalBlock1$ctl00$ctl00$MemberForm$memberFormRepeater$ctl22$ctl03" type="hidden">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```